# google sheet overwrite existing database

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to this custom script and I have found it difficult to find a script.

When I hit the **"edit" button** it will automatically save to the **"ID Database"**, but it just creates a new line, not overwriting the existing database file.

Really need a script to replace the existing data with the newest data, when I click the **"update" button**.

To overwrite the  existing data, I have attached the link to the sheet >> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1orpHAJJvTUu3b0JoehR-9iOzDtvsPu457QzPDJ58A/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance ^^

Kat

Comment: Dont have access to the sheet

Comment: You have to give to sharing url to make it work @Kat

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming it’s just a request to get free a free script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Edit save Id.gs file you are indeed setting the values to the last row:

```
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues(values);
```

To update the values from the row you chose you have to search if the ID of the ID entry sheet is = to the ID of the database and then modify that row.

You have to change this:

```
var values = [[formSS.getRange("D2").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues(values);
```

to this:

```
var databaseValues = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < databaseValues.length; i++) {
    if (databaseValues[i][0] == formSS.getRange("D2").getValue()) {
      datasheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(formSS.getRange("D4").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(formSS.getRange("D5").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue(formSS.getRange("D6").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(i+1, 5).setValue(formSS.getRange("D7").getValue());
      break;
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to help! For documentation purposes if you can, please [accept the answer (✓)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kessy. You're a gem!